# How to play external audio files in ionic

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new in ionic cordova and I am having some issues trying to play audio file eg. mp3 in my app. The platform is android. I have gone through the angular js documentation, but I seem to be getting more confused.

This is my controller

```js
.controller('AudioCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaMedia) {

  var src = "/android_asset/www/audio/gingle.mp3";
  var media = $cordovaMedia.newMedia(src).then(function() {
    // success
  }, function () {
    // error
  });

  $scope.playAudio = function(){
    media.play(); 
  }
  $scope.stopAudio = function(){
    media.stop();
  }
  $scope.pauseAudio = function(){
     media.pause();
  }
});
```

and this the page the plays the audio

```html
<ion-view title="Audio Message">
    <ion-content class="has-header padding" ng-controller="AudioCtrl">

        
        <button ng-click="playAudio()">Play Audio</button>
        <button ng-click="stopAudio()">stop Audio</button>
         <button ng-click="pauseAudio()">pause Audio</button>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: What are you getting? Error messages? Some debug stuff? Please, when you're having problem with something, be specific.

Comment: When I run the project on a device nothing happens, however, in the browser, this is the error message that comes.   "ReferenceError: Media is not defined
    at Object.newMedia "

Comment: Any help? I am stuck for 2 days!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using ngCordova plugins?

They have a native audio one:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/SidneyS/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio.git
```

You can use it like so:

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaNativeAudio, $timeout) {

  $cordovaNativeAudio
    .preloadSimple('click', 'audio/click.mp3')
    .then(function (msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    }, function (error) {
      alert(error);
    });

  $cordovaNativeAudio
    .preloadComplex('music', 'audio/music.mp3', 1, 1)
    .then(function (msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    }, function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });

  $scope.play = function () {
    $cordovaNativeAudio.play('click');
    $cordovaNativeAudio.loop('music');

    // stop 'music' loop and unload
    $timeout(function () {
      $cordovaNativeAudio.stop('music');

      $cordovaNativeAudio.unload('click');
      $cordovaNativeAudio.unload('music');
    }, 1000 * 60);
  };

});
```